# Android device adb always unauthorized on linux/Mac

Tags: android, adb

I've had to deal with this one a few times and every time I forget what the cause is until I dig deep. So here are the symptoms:

- Every time you reconnect/reboot the device you get the authorization dialog even though you could *swear* you checked the *Always* checkbox the last time.
- `adb shell` gives you the blurb below
- `adb devices` gives you the other blurb below
- You cannot connect via adb while in recovery
- Device is unauthorized and plugging it in won't display the authorization dialog

The `adb shell` *blurb*:

```
user@PC:~$ adb shell
error: device unauthorized.
This adbd's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set; try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
```

The `adb devices` *blurb*:

```
user@PC:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached
C4F124F1B9A98AE unauthorized
```

Your udev rules are in place and the codes outputted from `lsusb` are present in your `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` (or the redhat equivalent, if different)

What's happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, for me, the issue has been what you see below:

```
user@PC:~$ ls -al ~/.android/
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  3 user    user 4096 Jun  7 15:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 30 user    user 4096 Sep 19 11:30 ..
-rw-------  1 root    root 1704 Jun  7 15:46 adbkey
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root  710 Jun  7 15:46 adbkey.pub
drwxrwxr-x  2 user    user 4096 Jun  7 15:42 cache
```

Notice how my `adbkey` and the matching public key are owned by root?
The first time I've ran `adb anything` on this machine has been as root.
The fix is easy and you probably already know it: `sudo chown user:user ~/.android/adbkey*`

Comment: Thanks, that worked great for me as well! PS: It should be `user:group` instead of `user.user`.  Usually your group is staff which makes the whole command:  `sudo chown USERNAME:staff ~/.android/adbkey*`

Comment: Most systems can use both '.' and ':' as the separator. Try it :)

Comment: Seems like '.' doesn't work on OSX, and for some reason I guessed this was OSX specific. It went a bit fast, sorry about that.

Comment: Ah ... I knew that :) Except I couldn't remember _which_ system annoyed me by not letting me use '.'.

Comment: I had to delete the file .android/adbkey and then it worked.

Comment: @desgua Yes, deleting it would regenerate the file with proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when moving to a new Mac and copying over Android Studio using a full Time Machine backup. After doing some research (which actually did not lead to the reason) just the reinstall of Android Studio solved the problem.